# Does HILT supports injecting generic types?

Tags: android, generics, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am getting below error during compilation, using HILT for DI.

> Component methods cannot have type variables

Its complaining about the below code

```
public abstract class BaseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        @EntryPoint
        @InstallIn(ApplicationComponent.class)
        interface BaseDialogFragmentEntryPoint {
                public <T extends ViewModelBase> T T();
        }

        protected ViewModelBase dataContext;

        protected <T extends ViewModelBase> T configure(Class<T> type)
        {
                BaseDialogFragmentEntryPoint baseDialogFragmentEntryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), BaseDialogFragmentEntryPoint.class);
                T viewModel = baseDialogFragmentEntryPoint.T();
                this.dataContext = viewModel;
                return viewModel;
        }

}
```

ViewModelBase class is extended by number of classes.

Does HILT support injecting generic objects? I have not found much information on this regarding HILT.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to override an instance of `ViewModel` from your "BaseFragment" to "ChildFragment", you can create an abstract variable in Base, and initialize it using `by viewModels()` delegate that kotlin provides. In order to be able to create the instance of ViewModel, you'll also need to annotate your ViewModel with `@HiltViewModel` annotation. Checkout the example from [documentaion](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack)

And here is example that I use

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T : ViewModel> : Fragment() {
     abstract val viewModel: T
     ......
}
```

> 

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment: BaseFragment<MyViewModel>() {
    override val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
    .....
}
```

> 

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel
@Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    ......
}
```